# MySQL error 1822: failure to add foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I've created 4 tables and my foreign keys for flight run fine, but when I try to run the alter statements for the table airport I get the error:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
> index for constraint 'airport_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'city'

My assignment is to add foreign keys, for every field with the _FK suffix, I'm not too sure what I should change to fix the error. If someone could lead me in the right direction it would be super helpful, thanks.

```
CREATE DATABASE airtraffic;
USE airtraffic;

CREATE TABLE plane (
    ID INTEGER,
    Type CHAR(20),
    NumPassenger INTEGER,
    CargoSize INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE city (
    Name CHAR(20),
    Nation CHAR(10),
    Population INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE airport (
    Code CHAR(3),
    City_FK CHAR(20),
    Nation_FK CHAR(10),
    NumTracks INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE flight (
    FlightID CHAR(10),
    DayOfWeek CHAR(10),
    DepartureAirport_FK CHAR(3),
    DepartureTime TIME,
    ArrivalAirport_FK CHAR(3),
    ArrivalTime TIME,
    Plane_FK INTEGER
);

-- primary keys
ALTER TABLE plane
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
    
ALTER TABLE city
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (Name, Nation);

ALTER TABLE airport
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (Code);
    
ALTER TABLE flight
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (FlightID);

-- foreign keys
-- getting an error for FKs for airport
ALTER TABLE airport 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (City_FK) REFERENCES city(Name),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Nation_FK) REFERENCES city(Nation);

-- this is working fine
ALTER TABLE flight 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (DepartureAirport_FK) REFERENCES airport(Code),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArrivalAirport_FK) REFERENCES airport(Code),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Plane_Fk) REFERENCES plane(ID);
```

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key should reference the entire primary key of `city`, not each column separately.

```
ALTER TABLE airport
ADD FOREIGN KEY (City_FK, Nation_FK) REFERENCES city(Name, Nation);
```